# CAPTCHA или ограничение количества попыток входа?

Tags: php, captcha

Зачем нужно делать ограничение количества попыток входа в аккаунт, которое дополнительно нагружает систему (пусть и слегка), если можно просто сделать капчу? И если боты научились обходить капчу, то начерта тогда она нужна?

Comment: Наверное самой главный минус капчи в том, что она довольно сильно раздражает пользователя, а это может привести к тому, что он просто передумает производить вход в систему и, возможно, покинет Ваш ресурс.

Comment: Но ведь есть же та капча, где нужно просто нажать на чекбокс, и все. Не знаю, как всем, а мне дак даже нравится такой ее вид. Или я еще чего-то не понимаю?

Comment: Вы говорите про `reCaptcha`. Это хороший компромисс. Она предлагает нажать на чекбокс, только если нет подозрений на автоматизацию.

Comment: Если считаете, что реКапча никак не смущает Ваших пользователей, то, возможно это действительно более удачный вариант. Могу предположить только один минус - для постоянных посетителей, у которых для формы входа включено автозаполнение, нажатие на капчу займет одно лишнее действие, что наверное даже не кретично, но всеже всегда найдется недовольный пользователь, которому это не понравиться.

Answer (score 1):

Ограничение количества попыток входа в аккаунт делается, к примеру, для того, чтобы нельзя было подобрать пароль брутфорсом.
Попробуйте поставить чистый Wordpress, дайте ему прописаться в Гугле и через месяц посмотрите логи сервера - боты со всего мира ломятся в wp-login и xmlrpc.php.

Аналогичные вещи происходят со всеми популярными CMS, а вот почему в них на входе в админ-панель практически нигде не ставят капчу по умолчанию - это загадка, решение которой, вероятно, связано с удобством массового пользования ради меньшей безопасности.

Впрочем, для каждой популярной CMS рано или поздно появляются плагины или другие решения, затрудняющие проникновение роботов внутрь.

Answer (score 0):

Капча создает некоторое неудобство для пользователя, поэтому ее включают как последний рубеж обороны. И в основном не на страницах входа, а на разных формах обратной связи.

Не знаю, где вы прочитали сказки про обход капчи ботами. По личному опыту: боты повалили на один из сайтов, поставил гуглокапчу - отрезало в ту же секунду и навсегда.

Comment: Да, она его создает, но снова тот же вопрос, что и господину выше, какое неудобство может создать NoCAPTCHA (Да, уже нашел, как она называется) пользователю? Я что один такой извращенец, которому даже нравится нажимать на этот чекбокс, и потом смотреть на анимацию?

Comment: На самом деле пробить Рекапча2 не особо проблема, просто это довольно дорого, и замедляет скорость. Т.е. если ваш сайт один из 100.000 то заморачиваться им никто не будет, а если один из 1000 то может и попасть.

Comment: @DeuS7 лично я считаю - никаких неудобств. Но встречал клиентов, которые просили NoCAPTCHA убрать со своего сайта  ))